# How to connect the views I created on Dynamics 365 with Power BI?

Tags: api, powerbi, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have managed to connect Dynamics with Power BI but I only see normal tables in the list but not the views. I tried doing something similar to the article here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/convert-your-dynamics-365ce-views-power-bi-dataset-matteo-sacco/   but I kept getting an error message telling me that the resource 'my view's name' does not exist. Any ideas?

Comment: As you mentioned, you can connect to D365. are you able to connect to an entity let's say for example opportunity as mentioned in the article you referred. Following the steps mentioned in article should give you results. May be give us some more info in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would have followed the post as is - he is doing multiple steps.

1. Creating view in CRM with apt columns and filters
2. Downloading the fetchxml query that was generated for that particular view
3. Encoding the fetchxml content and using in CRM web api endpoint `https://yourcrm.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/opportunities?fetchXml=%3Cfetch...`

Once you prepared this URI - you can paste it in browser to see json response. If it works, then use it in PowerBI Odata feed.

One thing to mention is - whenever you are changing the view query, these steps has to be done every single time. There is no shortcut to use the definition stored in CRM view as is in PowerBI directly.

Probably you are changing the view name in place of entity name. i.e. `opportunities`, you should not do that. Since Web api is trying to parse your view name as entity - and you are getting "resource not found" error message. :)

Btw, instead of `opportunities`, use your entity plural name for which view is built. FYI - views are stored in savedquery and userquery tables.